# "Unexpected token else" error

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Codecademy lesson on if/else statements and I repeatedly get an error saying, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else". Please help. Here is the code:

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!

confirm("I am ready to play!");

var age=prompt("What is your age?");

if(age<13)
{
    console.log("You are allowed to play, but I take no responsibility");
}else{
    confirm("Play On!");
}

console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");

console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");

var userAnswer=prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");

if(userAnswer==="yes");
{
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
}else{
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
};
```

Comment: `if(userAnswer==="yes");` should be `if(userAnswer==="yes")`. The semi-colon terminates the if-statement prematurely.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo.

Comment: Next time, examine which line the Javascript console is reporting the error at and look in the adjacent lines for typos or something unusual. Will save you a lot of time and headaches.

Comment: Should be closed just because it contains the text "You are at a Justin Bieber concert"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(userAnswer==="yes");
```

just remove the ";"

```
if(userAnswer==="yes")
```

Here's why - JavaScript (and truthfully most languages out there) will interpret the if below:

```
if (condition); 
    statement;
```

as a no-op and optimize it away, because what the above pseudocode actually means is:

```
if (condition) <nothing!>; 
    statement;
```

Comment: Instead of answering a question where the issue is due to a typo and farm rep from it, vote to close it as off-topic instead.

Comment: Or, if you're going to post an answer, explain _why_ the typo causes a problem.